/user/login 403 You are not authorized to access this page
I'm using Drupal 10 with Nginx and Basic Auth.
On the user/login page, I get a "You are not authorized to access this page. 403" error.
I can see the menu, but I do not see the login form.
When I remove Basic Auth, everything works, but with Basic Auth, it does not work.
I have this in my config:
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area!";
    auth_basic_user_file /example/example/.htpasswd;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

Any idea what the problem is?

I found a solution: the problem occurs if you have the Basic Auth module enabled in Drupal, as it causes a conflict. There is currently a patch that works, but you can read more details here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2842858
